# Can't convert matrix in R to itemMatrix to facilitate collaborative filtering

Tags: r, matrix, collaborative-filtering

I have a large, sparse binary matrix in R that I want to coerce to an itemMatrix so I can perform collaborative filtering. When I run:

```
i <- as(m, "itemMatrix")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in t(as(from, "ngCMatrix")) 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': Error in             asMethod(object) : cannot coerce 'NA's to "nsparseMatrix"
```

When I convert the original matrix to a data frame and replace the matrix in the code, I get the following error:

```
Error in asMethod(object) 
can not coerce list with transactions with duplicated items
```

I double checked my dataset for missing values and find none. What could the problem be that is preventing the conversion to an itemMatrix?

Comment: tell us the package you are using (arules?) and provide a small example object and code.

Comment: Yeah I was using arules, as you have to in order to facilitate certain actions in the Recommenderlab package. In the end, I coerced the original data in table form to a sparse matrix, coerced that to an ngCMatrix, then coerced THAT to an itemMatrix.